# C++ Boost graph library: Isomorphism with edge property

Tags: c++, boost, graph, isomorphism

The boost graph library has an isomorphism function with a very minimal example:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/graph/example/isomorphism.cpp

I need to find isomorphism between two graphs with a very minimal extension, that each line has two properties, that can be indicated with integer values. I guess this is equivalent to a weight.

I cannot for the life of me understand the role of property maps or how to incorporate those.  Could someone point me to a relevant example so I can see how this works?

Comment: I am not sure that boost graph can handle this. It is made for unlabeled graphs(at least the function you are trying to use) whereas your graphs seem labeled (by the two integers).

Comment: If you showed code that you had it would be far easier to demonstrate something. R.n. we even have to come up with graph models, sample data, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot generate such a closed form code as it is embedded in a rather large project.  I think the intent of my question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Boost.Graph uses "property maps" to associate data with different graph elements (i.e. vertices, edges, or the graph as a whole).  A property map is simply a container that can associate the graph's internal descriptor types to some other data.  A few examples can be found [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html) and [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html).

I assume you've already seen [the docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/graph/doc/isomorphism.html) for the `isomorphism` function.  So in your case each of your graphs will have one property map for edge weights, and then you have the option to provide more property maps when calling the `isomorphism` function to control the behavior and/or get extra data out.  However, I don't see any way to provide a predicate for verifying that the edge weights match; you may have to handle that yourself (e.g. first run the function to check for "pure" isomorphism, then walk edges of one graph and use the output `isomorphism_map` to find corresponding edges in the second graph and check equality)

Comment: Property maps are not like containers. They are like references that know how to find/update data (e.g. in a container)

Comment: That is a great suggestion.  Unfortunately in the situation I have, what you propose will not work. 

The reason for this is that since some information is dropped from the graph, the isomorphism_map is not unique.  So if you pick a particular map and then check for edge equivalence, your result will sometimes be true and sometimes be false. If it is true, then you are fine. But if it is false, this does not preclude a different isomorphism_map from having the same edge properties.

If there isa way to make the isomorphism function continue if it does not find a match then this would work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell that algorithm doesn't allow you to specify edge equivalence criteria. Perhaps you can apply [vf2_sub_graph_iso](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/graph/doc/vf2_sub_graph_iso.html), though, which takes an optional `EdgeEquivalencePredicate`

Comment: Yes this might be a solution if i'm able to define subgraphs as the entire graph or something like that, I will see about that.